# EDITED!! uncalled getter function causes the JPanel to reprint in the wrong location

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

This is quite bizarre, I have a gui program that allows user to update a J panel by detecting mouseclick
every time the mouse click is detected, the JPanel repaints itself. for some reason the repaint is off by like 30-40 pixels even though through testings,it shows that they are painting at the exact same coordinates. This problem is solved however after I minimize and then re-maximize the window .

the repaint is called in the after detecting mouse click in the same method

Edit: below is a minimum reproduction of that error

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class CenterPanel extends JPanel{
    private  int sideLength = 50;
    private  int x = 10;
    private  int y = 10;

    public CenterPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x*sideLength,y*sideLength));
        addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,3));
        try {
            createCanvas(x,y,g,sideLength);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCanvas(int x, int y, Graphics g, int sideLength) throws InterruptedException {
        int coordX=0;
        int coordY=0;
        for(int i=0; i<x;i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<x;j++) {
                paintRectangle(g,Color.LIGHT_GRAY,coordX,coordY,sideLength-1,sideLength-1);
                coordX=coordX+sideLength;
            }
            coordX=0;
            coordY=coordY+sideLength;
        }
    }

    private static void paintRectangle(Graphics g,Color color,int x, int y,int width,int height) throws InterruptedException {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }   

    class Mouse extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener{

    private static Color currentColor = Color.lightGray;

    private static Color defaultColor = Color.lightGray;

    private CenterPanel centerPanel;
    JButton red, yellow, white, pink, orange, magenta, light_gray, green, gray, dark_gray, cyan, blue, black; 

    public TestFrame() {
        centerPanel=new CenterPanel();
        gui();
    }

    private void gui() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel ();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel ();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel ();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel ();
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        c.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        c.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);       

        this.setVisible(true);

        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFrame t=new TestFrame();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Edit2: I performed another test by adding Jpanels to North South and West borderlayout locations and find out that the center borderlayout location (the one canvas is in) is misaligned and was overlapping with other Jpanels and was fixed after repaint. Which seems to be whats causing the change in Canvas location.

Edit3: photo of said experiment
[image]

Update: I changed setSize() of the CenterPanel Jpanel to setPreferredSize(). now the overlapping shows up without having to call repaint (mouse click).

**UPDATE!!! I have narrowed the problem down to the getter function in the CenterPanel  **

```
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
```

these two. if I remove them the problem disappears. The problem is I still dont understand why the two getter function could cause this issue when they aren't even called???

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi, I am unsure what is causing the precise issue so I shared a lot more code than would normally considered a minimal reproducible example hope you don't mind

Comment: Hi thanx for pointing that out. I have deleted pretty much everything that is unrelated and it seems that the repaint called in the mouseClicked method in the MouseAdapter class is causing this issue

Comment: I still don't understand why tho

Comment: Hi I have narrowed the problem down to two getter method. But I am beyond baffled as to why they could affect the program when they are 1) getter methods and 2) not even called. Could you please check it out? thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `JComponent`s (the superclass of `JPanel`) [`getX()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX%28%29) and [`getY()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getY%28%29).

When the position of your panel is determined, it will call those two getters and use them as the coordinates - in pixels.

Name your getters in a different way.
And enable your IDE's warning WRT missing `@Override` annotations.

Comment: wasted way too long on this one

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a MyFrame class?
I tried with this code and it worked well:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

public class App extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.start();
    }

    public static Color getCurrentColor() {
        return Color.GREEN.darker();
    }

    public void start() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        add(new Canvas());
    }

    public static Color getDefaultColor() {
        return Color.BLUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the MyFrame class to my questions.

Comment: Incorporating your code in my program wasn't able to solve the issue. it seems the mouse action triggered repaint was still painting in the wrong location

Comment: Hi I have narrowed the problem down to two getter method. But I am beyond baffled as to why they could affect the program when they are 1) getter methods and 2) not even called. Could you please check it out? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
super.paintComponents(g);
```

with

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: that seemed to solve the layering issue but the repaint is still in the mismatched location